# WiFi IC with minimal controller features

Tags: esp8266, wifi, alternatives

I do not want to program my esp8266. Are there any alternatives to it with lesser controlling abilities (I/O lines, Flash, etc)?

Comment: I'll be connecting it on board with my controller.

Comment: If you say "alternatives"" but "with lesser controlling abilities ", what exactly do you need and what not? What do you wnat to achiev? Do you want to avoid programming altogether? (why?) without I/O lines a module won't be able to do much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are firmwares for the ESP8266 which allow you to do everything over a serial (UART) connexion, using commands that look a bit like a hayes command set, and other modules are available which work similarly.

Here are [the AT commands for the ESP8266](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf) and you can drive that interface using only a UART from something like an arduino and 2 wires

There are plenty of libraries for driving the ESP8266 over a uart [here's one for arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino)

There are also plenty of SPI and SDIO wifi modules (but you'll end up having to 
implement a good chunk of the large 802.11 stack yourself in your microcontroller, that's easy if you've got something like VxWorks on Linux on your other controller, less so if it's a little embedded device)

Personally I suspect (unless you find a library which does exactly what you want), you'll end up doing more work writing to the code to interface with the wifi module, than you would have in programming the ESP8266 to do most of the
work for you.